# Last observation carried forward conditional on value and colums

Tags: r, imputation, locf

I have a longhitudinal dataframe with a lot of missing values that looks like this.

```
ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
date = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
cond = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
var = c(1, NA , 2, 0,NA, NA, 3, NA,0, NA, 2, NA, 1,NA,NA)
df = data.frame(ID, date, cond,var)
```

I would like to carry forward the last observation based on two conditions:

1) when `cond=0` it should carry on the observation the higher value of the variable of interest.

2) when `cond=1` it should carry forward the lower value of the variable of interest.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could do this in an elegant way?

The final dataset should look like this

```
ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
date = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
cond = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
var = c(1, 1 , 2, 0, 0, NA, 3, 3, 0, 0,2,2,2,2,2)
final = data.frame(ID, date, cond,var)
```

So far I was able to carry forward the last observation, but I was unable to impose the conditions

```
library(zoo)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(var = 
           na.locf(var, na.rm = F))
```

any suggestion is welcomed

Comment: Your logic seems to be `df %>% group_by(ID, cond) %>% mutate(var = if(all(!cond)) replace(var, is.na(var), max(var, na.rm = TRUE)) else replace(var, is.na(var), min(var, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: I test it and let you know

Comment: It is not giving the expected output.  But, I showed it just to understand your logic

Comment: For some reasons in the real data it produces an error: R - " missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". not sure why this is the case. Another doubt is whether the logic would work if I have two observed values one after the other- i.e.  `var = c(1,2,NA, 2, 0,NA, NA, 3, NA,0, NA, 2, 1,NA,NA,NA)`

Comment: Based on your logic, why is the 2nd value 1 in `final`.  `cond=0 it should carry on the observation the higher value of the variable of interest.`

Comment: Yes, this is the case perfect! thank you very much! but what may cause the error in the real data? it is not clear. Also, I have noticed that using it on the sample data, it does not precisely report the outcome expected. Running the command on `df` does not replace the lower value with the higher value. but only replaces missing value with the higher value. In other words, row 13 is rather than being a 1 in the outcome, it should be a 2

Comment: The error could be that you have `NA` in 'cond' column. So `if(all(!cond & !is.na(cond)))` shsould fix it

Comment: Great you were right, the  " missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" issue has gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the use of `accumulate2` ie

```
df%>%
   group_by(ID)%>%
   mutate(d = unlist(accumulate2(var,cond[-1],function(z,x,y) if(y) min(z,x,na.rm=TRUE) else max(z,x,na.rm=TRUE))))
# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID  date  cond   var     d
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     1     1
 2     1     2     0    NA     1
 3     1     3     0     2     2
 4     1     4     1     0     0
 5     1     5     0    NA     0
 6     2     1     0    NA    NA
 7     2     2     0     3     3
 8     2     3     0    NA     3
 9     2     4     1     0     0
10     2     5     0    NA     0
11     3     1     0     2     2
12     3     2     0    NA     2
13     3     3     0     1     2
14     3     4     0    NA     2
15     3     5     0    NA     2
```

Comment: @Alessandro if this works, you can accept it as the solution

Comment: Sure, only one concern, is there a way to avoid returning -inf? i.e. when applied to the real data it yield the following warning "In max(z, x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"

Comment: That is a scenario where the first element of the group is NA, thus you can put a condition within the function to take account of that.

Comment: not sure I fully understand, could you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think, if I understand what you are after is this?

```
ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
date = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
cond = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
var = c(1, NA , 2, 0,NA, NA, 3, NA,0, NA, 2, NA, 1,NA,NA)
df = data.frame(ID, date, cond,var)
```

Using `case_when` you can do some conditional checks. I'm unsure if you mean to return the minimum for all of the "ID" field, but this will look at the condition and then lag or lead to find a non missing value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(var_imput = case_when(
    cond == 0 & is.na(var)~lag(x = var, n = 1, default = NA),
    cond == 1 & is.na(var)~lead(x = var, n = 1, default = NA),
    TRUE~var
  ))
```

Which yields:

```
   ID date cond var var_imput
1   1    1    0   1         1
2   1    2    0  NA         1
3   1    3    0   2         2
4   1    4    1   0         0
5   1    5    0  NA         0
6   2    1    0  NA        NA
7   2    2    0   3         3
8   2    3    0  NA         3
9   2    4    1   0         0
10  2    5    0  NA         0
11  3    1    0   2         2
12  3    2    0  NA         2
13  3    3    0   1         1
14  3    4    0  NA         1
15  3    5    0  NA        NA
```

If you want to group by ID then you could generate an impute table by ID, then join it with the original table like this:

```
# enerate input table
input_table <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(min = min(var, na.rm = T),
            max = max(var, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  gather(cond, value, -ID) %>% 
  mutate(cond = ifelse(cond == "min", 0, 1))

# Join and impute missing
df %>% 
  left_join(input_table,by = c("ID", "cond")) %>% 
  mutate(var_imput = ifelse(is.na(var), value, var))
```